# VBA Copy & Find

Tags: vba, excel, copy

I have hunted online and not yet managed to find anything to covers what I need.

Hopefully this will make sense.

I need to copy the current cell, select sheet2, then find the string in that sheet.

I'm sure it's a simple bit of code and I have got it to the point where I can find the text, but only when I put it directly into the code. I just need it to use the current cell.

```
Sub Find()
Selection.Copy
Sheets("Sheet2").Select
Range("A1").Select
Cells.Find(What:="MYDATA", After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:= _
    xlFormulas, LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:= _
    xlNext, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False).Activate
End Sub
```

All help is gratefully received.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you share your code? I am suspecting it only needs a slight modification

Comment: You just need the `.Find()` method, which is extensively documented all over the internet.

Comment: If you say you can do the `Find`, perhaps you need to know how to use `ActiveCell.Value` instead of a hard-coded value.

Comment: Edited OP with current code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modified your code to include the value of the current cell as a variable **findValue** and then using that as the **what** argument in the **find** function.

Try this out:

```
Sub Find()
findValue = ActiveCell.Value
Sheets("Sheet2").Select
Range("A1").Select
Cells.Find(What:=findValue, After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:= _
    xlFormulas, LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:= _
    xlNext, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False).Activate
End Sub
```

Comment: Perfect. Thank you.